# Why is there a villain named after John W. Campbell, Jr. in Slaughterhouse Five?

Tags: kurt-vonnegut, slaughterhouse-five

*Slaughterhouse Five* by Kurt Vonnegut features, among its many other peculiar individuals, a traitorous American-turned-Nazi named Howard W. Campbell, Jr.  To a reader of mid-century science fiction, the name is an obvious allusion to writer and editor John W. Campbell, Jr.  Did Vonnegut have a grudge against Campbell that precipitated this?

Campbell was an interesting character.  On the one hand, he could be extremely credulous, believing in psychic powers and getting caught up in Scientology.  On the other hand, his fiction was sometimes extremely insightful.  He was actually the first person to notice that the infinities in relativistic quantum field theory could lead to the violation of classical conservation laws.  (His version of this in "Cloak of Aesir" was nothing like the actual functioning of quantum anomalies, but he did originate the concept, decades before it was uncovered by actual physicists.)

Comment: The character's appearance in S-5 is his second appearance. His first appearance was in Mother Night.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vonnegut claimed in a 1987 interview that the two were unconnected.

> **Nuwer:** *I should have. Glad I asked, anyway. Was the name of [your character] Howard W. Campbell, Jr. in Mother Night inspired by John W.
> Campbell, Jr. [leading editor of science fiction magazines Astounding
> Science Fiction and Analog]? I read some criticism [by critic James
> Lundquist] which said it might be. Was it?*
>
> **Vonnegut:** *Not at all. I know who he [John W. Campbell, Jr.] is, but I never had a damn thing to do with him. No. I guess he had
> enemies, but I don't know that much about him. But I gather that he
> was a controversial person. Hell, no.*
>
> <sub><sup>[A Skull Session with Kurt Vonnegut](http://filling-form.info/doc/2901/index.html?page=23)</sup></sub>

Given the similarity of the names, the ungenerous interpretation of Howard Campbell's character and the fact the John W. Campbell was responsible for rejecting a number of Vonnegut's early works, I think we'd be forgiven for thinking that he's lying.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the fact that JWC rejected some of Vonnegut's stories, and do you know which stories those were?

Comment: So... Vonnegut says it's a coincidence, but it seems like he's dissembling.

Comment: @user14111 - Apparently it was mentioned in a panel discussion about Vonnegut (https://skemman.is/bitstream/1946/2983/1/endanlegt_fixed.pdf - Pg. 10)

Comment: @Valorum: the fact that Campbell rejected some of Vonnegut’s stories is pretty key to what you’re suggesting as the answer here — might it make sense to include a quote about that in the answer itself?